# How can docker understand if request call is make for internal or external if using ip only

Tags: docker

I am newbie in Docker and trying to catch up. Considering a docker container with a Java application, and a external database server (`not in host system, but remote to host system`) with ip `10.24.198.1` and it is passed to docker as environment parameter

```
docker run ... -e JDBC_URL="jdbc:mysql://10.24.198.1:3306/serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true"
```

I have a few questions

1. How can docker tell if the datasource is made to be internal (based on ip) or external (so to make attempt to connect externally)?
2. How to inform Docker container that the jdbc datasource is external so do not make attempt to make internal validation.
3. What is functional difference to set the JDBC value via `-e` parameter or define it in `Dockerfile`, other than flexibility (dynamic setting via `-e` vs hard coded in Dockerfile)

Comment: "*I have a few questions*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: To the first point: the docker host acts (as far as I know) as gateway/router and DNS server for all containers. The host knows what IPs are internal, and what are external. If we try contact an external source that has an ip address in the docker IP range, this will fail. Tot he second point: the container inherits the DNS settings from the host.

Comment: To the third point: the [`ENV`directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) declares an environment variable with an optional value. It can be overrideen with `docker run -e ...`. Having the `ENV` directive in a containerfile makes it easier to see what environment variables a containerfile uses.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks. Regarding 2nd point, is there a way to directly inform docker to access the ip/jdbc url externally  instead treating it as internal ip? In the case of ip address is in range of container and host, how to ask container to connect it externally?

Comment: No. As i said: if the external IP is in thedocker-internal IP range, then this is problematic. We can, however, reconfigure the IP range used by docker. See, for example, [this post over at `serverfault.com`](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range).